# How to connect elsticache Redis in my localhost with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, amazon-elasticache

Can I connect Redis ElastiCache with Rails from my localhost?

This is my Security Groups configuration.[image]

this is my endpoint from secrets.yml

```
redis_url: 'redis://[name_endpoint]:6379'
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's poorly documented and an odd design decision, but [Elasticache is not accessible from outside your VPN](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/faqs/) not matter what you do with your security groups. There is a [workaround](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html), but it's painful and requires extra boxes.